# MYSQL group by query

Tags: mysql

I have following table in my MySQL database

**busnames**

```
id |busname
```

**routes**

```
id|route_name
```

**timings table**

```
id | bus_id | route_id | trip |direction |bus_time
```

- one bus contain many trips per day
- each trip contain 2 direction (0|1)
- 0 means source to destination
- 1 means destination to source

Now I want to display data group by trip where bus_id="some_id" and for each page per trip data. If I click next, then I need to show second trip data

```
BusRouteName |Trip | Departure | Destination|

Newyork        1         8 a.m       10.am
Ausi           1         9 a.m       11.20 a.m
```

In the above data bus traveling from Newyork at 8 a.m and return at 10.am in first trip

I have tried many queries in MySQL, but it doesn't seem to produce the correct output

```
SELECT * FROM timings t inner join routes r on t.route_id=r.id inner join busnames b on t.bus_id=b.id where b.id=1
```

Can anyone tell me how can I get the data based on trip?

Comment: Why the Oracle and sqlite tags?

Comment: vote down people please post why you have voted down ,so i can improve whats wrong i made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to group by the BusRoute and Trip and use the min and max values of the bus_time to get the departure and destination time.

Something like this (not tested):

```
SELECT r.route_name, t.trip, min(t.bus_time) as Departure, max(t.bus_time) as Destination FROM timings t 
inner join routes r on t.route_id=r.id 
inner join busnames b on t.bus_id=b.id 
where b.id=1
group by r.route_name, t.trip
```

If you have more complex conditions you can look at the partition by function. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-selection.html

Comment: Unknown column 'b.id=1' in 'having clause'

Comment: Why HAVING clause instead of WHERE?

Comment: @FabianLang.its ok no problem .any way thank you for the answer